# SQL Server - How to track down error thrown in SSDT publish preview?

Tags: sql-server, ssdt

Without flailing through a file search, how does one track down the code that caused an error during SSDT publish preview?

Normally any errors come later such that the statement can be traced in the publish preview, but when the error comes in the preview I see no clear way to find what caused it.

I manually tracked it down this time (to a **valid** statement!):
[image: View Preview unclickable]
(The error about I.RowNum is the same thing)

**Update:** The faulty code was in a stored procedure *already existing* on the server. Even though I removed it from my database project it still failed the publish preview, so I had to delete it from the server to make the publish work.  So a file search didn't even work to find the code it flagged.

**Update 2:** The error isn't actually failing the publish preview (at least by itself), it is just shown *only* when the step fails (I have since seen it appear again). The actual error is still unknown as the only other messages were data loss warnings that the advanced settings were set to allow. I am now confused more than ever.

Probably related: [Update to SSDT started throwing ambiguous column name errors on valid SQL](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2013/07/01/june-2013-release-of-ssdt-contains-a-minor-bug-that-you-should-be-aware-of.aspx)

Also related: [Unaliased ORDER BY columns.](https://naturalselectiondba.wordpress.com/2017/03/10/sql-server-issues-i-have-with-ssdt-based-deployments-part-4-2/)

So I'm guessing this is actually a bug in SSDT at this point. Can anybody confirm? **I'd still like to know how to track down the buggy code** when it is on the server and fails the publish preview.

Thanks.

Comment: The build always succeeds, whether I clean first, or just rebuild.

Comment: There are no database references, and unfortunately I cannot share the publish XML because I can't reveal our software at all.

Comment: I removed the only reference I found searching for "CE.RowNum" and manually deleted the bin and obj folders, cleaned, and rebuilt the project. It still fails with the same error when publishing. Add on top of that, the query with that "CE.RowNum" reference is valid as far as I can tell!

Comment: I restarted VS and it is still failing the same. Not a single file contains the string "CE.RowNum"